# once a thread is done, notify main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

my winform has a thread running and I need it to notify main thread once it's done, then the main thread can set progressbar back to normal state.

currently, what i have is something as following

```
------begin---------
// codes before....
call thread one....
create thread two instance then start thread two
---------end------------------
```

in thread two, i have

```
--------begin------
 while(threadOne.isalive){
   Thread.Sleep(500);
 }
 call setProgressbar delegate
 ---------end----------------
```

i did this instead of put an var in thread one is because thread one is recursive method....
i wonder if this correct way of doing it, can someone help? 
thanks

Comment: Have you thought about Event based approach. Eg: EventWaitHandle ( Autoreset or ManualReset )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The answer below the line answers your explicit question, but if you're using .NET 4, you should consider thinking at a higher level of abstraction instead - tasks. The Task Parallel Library exposes a richer set of functionality than "bare" threads, and you can do things like registering continuations (with [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235663.aspx)) - and there you can even specify which task scheduler to use, so you can directly specify that when a background task has finished, a particular action should be invoked *on the UI thread*.

---

**Original answer**

The simplest way would be to delegate the first thread's responsibility, e.g.

```
public void WrappedStart()
{
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        StartWork();
        success = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        NotifyCompleted(success);
    }
}

private void StartWork()
{
    // Do your real work here
}

...

Thread t = new Thread(WrappedStart);
t.Start();
```

If your thread might do different things, you could change your `WrapperStart` to take the action to wrap:

```
public void WrappedStart(Action action)
{
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => WrappedStart(RealWork));
t.Start();
```

Note that if you *do* want the multi-thread solution, just use [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) instead of looping explicitly.

Comment: i tried join before, it simply hangs my program for some reason

Comment: @ikel: What thread were you calling it from? You don't want to call `Join` from the UI thread, for example. (You shouldn't be doing *any* blocking calls like that from the UI thread.)

Comment: i forgot which thread i called join from, it was at beginning of coding. but thanks for your point, i will try again.

Comment: thank you all for the help, i changed my code and tested work fine with Jon's method

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a delegate to handle the update of the progress bar.
2. When a progress occurs on the child thread, use [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) to call the defined delegate to update the UI.

Comment: but my thread one is recursive, how can it only call delegate for progressbar only once??

Comment: Don't you have a termination condition on your recursion?